# How to uniquely identify ARM devices without relying on MAC-address?

Tags: linux, arm

I've a bunch of ARM devices. They don't differ in hardware. Can I somehow obtain a unique ID for each device without using MAC-address? This ID must stay the same even if I reflash the NAND with a new kernel and rootfs. Its hardware based on the Atmel AT91SAM9.

Comment: Why not use the MAC address which is made exactly for that?

Comment: @JuliePelletier Because it is not a reliable method. In several ARM SBCs when loading the boot confs and firmware files, you end up with the same *default* MAC.

Comment: What kind of ARM device? There's no standard device identifier, each manufacturer makes their own.

Comment: @Gilles Updated question.

Answer (score 7):

Get the serial of the device from /proc/cpuinfo

```
grep Serial /proc/cpuinfo 
Serial      : 1651660a0642ebb0
```

(taken from my A20 based SoC, [Lamobo R1](http://linux-sunxi.org/Lamobo_R1) aka Banana Pi R1 and ArmBian/Jessie with kernel 4.5.2)

```
grep Serial /proc/cpuinfo 
Serial          : 64355040058f0d000000
```

(taken from my H3 based Soc, [Orange Pi One](http://linux-sunxi.org/Xunlong_Orange_Pi_One) with Armbian/Jessie kernel 3.4)

[Getting Your Raspberry Pi Serial Number Using Python](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2012/09/getting-your-raspberry-pi-serial-number-using-python/)

About this serial number : It is supposed to be unique, but it is read differently on different SoCs. And sometimes either software or configurations fail.

[SID Register Guide](http://linux-sunxi.org/SID_Register_Guide)

> Few use cases for the SID are, but not limited to:
>   - Generate
>   per-device unique MAC address
>   - Store/use as an RSA etc key
>   - Write
>   in-house serial numbers

In the raspberry this number is generally used as a SN to buy a video codec license. It is also known that the reading can fail [when u-boot is not properly configured](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=98036).

Not all ARM SoCs support this functionality. As per the updated question, the Atmel AT91SAM9 seems to not have this functionality. However, I will leave this answer here for others searching for it.

Comment: This isn't available on all ARM devices, and some devices with a `Serial` entry in `/proc/cpuinfo` don't actually populate it properly — my Banana Pis just say `Serial          : 0000000000000000`.

Comment: @StephenKitt Lamobo/ Banana PI R1 here with ArmBian, and working. I could swear it is a u-boot/Linux configuration matter for it to show. I will double check with a workmate that has one too. Out of curiosity, which distro?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I'm using Debian Stretch.

Comment: Like @StephenKitt already mentions. The serial can be 000000000 which is true in my case.

Comment: I googled around, and also confirmed it with someone more knowledgeable int the armbian forum, tkaiser). No word yet from my workmate with the plain Banana Pi

Answer (score 0):

Many devices have chips that may also offer unique ids. Your device may have an eMMC chip on the board which the Linux kernel likely has a sys entry for. The path might be something like:

```
/sys/bus/mmc/devices/mmc1:0000/serial
```

Just make sure you check several devices and consult the data sheet to make sure the number is truly unique. Note also that chip manufacturers can make mistakes, I've seen examples where a chip manufacturing run accidentally produced multiple chips with the same supposedly unique ID, so if possible concatenate two chip serial numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Readers who are looking for a more portable method may find `dmidecode` useful:

```
pi : 12:26:23 /root# dmidecode -s system-serial-number
1000000059d267e5
```